# Smtp exception could not send mails

Tags: c#, wpf, smtpclient

```
System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: 
Failure sending mail. ---> 
System.Net.WebException: 
Unable to connect to the remote server ---> 
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: 
No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it xx.x.xx.xxx:25
```

my **SMTP** host is above IP address I could not get mails it is throwing the above exception.

below is my code

```
mail.From = new MailAddress(email.From.EmailAddress,email.From.FullName);
mail.Subject = email.Subject;
mail.Body = email.Body;
if (email.Body.Contains("<html>"))
{
    mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
}
if (!email.ExcludeAttachment && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(email.AttachmentPath))
    mail.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(email.AttachmentPath));

client = new SmtpClient();
client.Host = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["SmtpServer"].ToString();
client.Send(mail);
```

Comment: mail.From = new MailAddress(email.From.EmailAddress,email.From.FullName);

          mail.Subject = email.Subject;
          mail.Body = email.Body;

          if (email.Body.Contains("<html>"))
          {
              mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
          }

          if (!email.ExcludeAttachment && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(email.AttachmentPath))
              mail.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(email.AttachmentPath));

          client = new SmtpClient();
          client.Host = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["SmtpServer"].ToString();
          client.Send(mail);

Comment: is this a work \ private smtp server or a public one like Office365, Gmail or hotmail..

Comment: The error is pretty clear, you can't reach the SMTP server from your machine. Are you sure you've got the correct host and that it is reachable (firewall and all)?

Answer (score 0):

The most probable reason you are getting this is because you need to authenticate against the server. You may need to send across the authentication too, take a look at my working code and see if you can adjust it to fit your needs.

It may also be worth grabbing Telrik Fiddler to see what the response is from the smtp sever

```
var client = new SmtpClient
        {
            Host = txtOutGoingServer.Text,
            Port = Convert.ToInt16(txtServerPort.Text),
            EnableSsl = true,
            DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
            Credentials = new NetworkCredential(txtUserName.Text, txtPassword.Password),
            Timeout = 20000
        };

 try
       {
           m.To.Add(new MailAddress(dr[0].ToString().Trim()));
           m.From = new MailAddress(txtUserName.Text);
           foreach (var attachment in Attactments)
       {
         m.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(attachment));
       }
         client.Send(m);
         m.To.Clear();
         m.Attachments.Clear();
         Success.Add(dr[0].ToString());
       }
         catch (SmtpException esException)
       {
         Errors.Add("Error sending to " + dr[0].ToString() + " " + esException.Message);
       }
         catch (Exception ex)
       {
         Errors.Add("Error sending to " + dr[0].ToString() + " " + ex.Message);

       }
```

The method that I am taking this working code from is looping through a datatable of email addresses and contact names, so just replace the dr[].ToString()... with whatever your values should be.

Comment: am getting DNS time out.

Comment: using this code? if so, try either taking the timeout out, or increasing the value

Comment: System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: The operation has timed out.
   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message)
   at EmailSender.PerformDelivery(IMessage message)

Comment: above is my exception message

Comment: ok, going back to my original question to you above, is this a public or private smtp server?